# Rendering wrong head with login layout

Tags: layout, ruby-on-rails-4, render

Can anyone tell me how it is possibile that the following layout in a Rails 4 app

```
# app/views/layout/login.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>PIPPO</title>
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
    <meta content="black-translucent" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />

    <link href="/assets/login.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/assets/login.js"></script>

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main-content">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the following controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'login'

  ...

  def destroy
    Session.find(session[:id]).close
    reset_session
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:success] = t('sessions.logout')
      format.html { redirect_to login_url }
    end
  end
end
```

and routes

```
...
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
...
```

produces the following HTML once I click on `<%= link_to 'logout', logout_path %>`?

```
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>PIPPO</title>
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
    <meta content="black-translucent" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />

    <link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/assets/application.js"></script>


    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="l9+umk+wjpXY4UFiKEeuQkGgMvjbbZ2uDxyJHowTJFo=" name="csrf-token" />
  </head>
```

Am I missing anything here? It is two days I'm trying to figure this out.
Why is it using the head from the main layout instead of the one in login?

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE - Forgot to mention my log file states:

> Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/login (1.4ms)

Answer (score 1):

As per the layout name given in the question, i.e.,

```
 app/views/layout.login.html.erb
```

There are couple of things wrong here:

- layouts should be placed in `app/views/layouts` folder
- File name should be `login.html.erb` and not `layout.login.html.erb`

In your case, Rails could not find `login.html.erb` in `app/views/layouts`, it rendered the default layout `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: It was a typo sorry. the layout is ```app/views/layout/login.html.erb```  Moreover the wrong head (the body is correct) is rendered only when I press the logout link not when I input http://example.com/login directly in the browser.